# calculate number of section in collectionview

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am having CollectionView with Dynamic Cell Size. I have implemented it successfully. But Now  i want fix row in all section like 
section 0 - 3 cell
section 1 - 2 cell
section 2 - 3 cell 
section 4 - 2 cell and So on..
How can i do this.
i have implemented **`numberOfItemsInSection`** like this

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
    {
        return 3;
    }
    else if (section % 2 != 0)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        return  3;
    }
}
```

but I am bit confusing to count **`numberOfSection`** How can I do this?

For Example : If i am having **8 items** to show. then i have **3 section** with **index 0 - 3 cell, index 2 - 2 cell and index 3 - 3 cell**. 
How can i do this for any numberofitems in collectionview.

Comment: just make it clear count numberOfSection, either show json or what do you want to show in collection view to get the correct answer.

Comment: write this method in  your numberOfItemsInSection method::::::::>> numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView)

Answer (score -1):

Example ::

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView)
    }
```

Comment: but the number of section are varie. as i explain in question. with each section having different number of items

Comment: numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView) this can give total section in coll.view store in one variable and use it.